# Unable to Toggle 'Live' for RestAPI Paypal

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments, paypal-rest-sdk

I am using **PayPal** for payments in one of my app. I have configured app at PayPal developer portal and it is working perfectly fine in sandbox environment. Now I am trying to make it live. I toggle button for Live transactions but it does not save. My account is **business account and authenticated**.After toggle **'Live'** from **sandbox**, it is returns back to sandbox on page refresh. Can anybody here guide me what can be possible issue.

Comment: I suggest you to file a ticket with MTS.

Answer (score 0):

May I know which feature you're trying to toggle?
For example, for Payouts services, you can just contact the PayPal Customer Support to toggle the service over the phone.